# Replace a combination of characters using regex java

Tags: java, regex

I have few string datasets in which I would like to replace a certain combination of characters using the regex replace in java. I tried multiple patterns but none of them helped. Could someone point me in the right pattern?

For example:

> hello,[cicuyuv v,]imijmijm

in this string i want to replace `",["` and `",]"` with a single `","` wherever occured.

```
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "hello,[cicuyuv v,]imijmijm"
            .replaceAll("[,[\\[]]", ",");

        System.out.println(data);

    }

}
```

Comment: `replaceAll(",[\\[\\]]", ",")`

Comment: `"hello,[cicuyuv v,]imijmijm".replaceAll(",[\\[\\]]", ",")` try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `"[,[\\[]]"` represents a `[,[\[]]` pattern that matches a single char, either a `,` or a `[` (the `[\[]` character class inside another character class formed a [*character class union*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html)).

You may use

```
String data = "hello,[cicuyuv v,]imijmijm".replaceAll(",[\\[\\]]", ",");
System.out.println(data); // -> hello,cicuyuv v,imijmijm
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/1ghHhR)

Here, `,[\[\]]` is a regex pattern that matches `,` and then a `[` or `]`. Please be very careful with `]` and `[` inside a character class in a Java regex: they must both be escaped (in other flavors, and when you test at regex101.com or other similar sites, `[` inside `[...]` does not have to be escaped. It is advised to use Java regex testing sites, like [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) or [Java Regular Expression Tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html) (no affiliation).

Comment: @Spara A hint: when I was an SO beginner, I earned points by posting answers that were just helpful, adding value to the already existing answers posted by more experienced regex users. This an off-topic conversation, I suggest you delete the comment above, and I will remove mine afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("hello,[cicuyuv v,]imijmijm".replaceAll(",(\\]|\\[)" , ","));


, matches the character , literally (case sensitive)

Capturing Group (\\]|\\[)

1st Alternative \]
\] matches the character ] literally (case sensitive)

2nd Alternative \[
\[ matches the character [ literally (case sensitive)
```